# O que o C++ pode fazer que o C# não pode?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

Sendo um programador .Net mas com uma antiga paixão por C++ (que cresceu desde o C++11), estive com essa curiosidade.

Eu sei que o .Net pode ser "extendido" com o C++/CLI, mas eu gostaria de saber o que o C# **puro** não consegue fazer, enquanto o C++ consegue.

**Nota:** Eu não quero opiniões aqui, e também não quero iniciar uma guerra das chamas. Eu quero **fatos**. Eu só quero saber o que o título da pergunta diz, não quero saber se você prefere uma linguagem ou outra porque *é mais fácil* fazer X nela.

**Atualização:** Depois de 4 respostas e algumas horas, estou julgando a do [@utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7742/1589) como a que melhor respondeu a minha pergunta, portanto estou marcando como aceita. A do [@FlávioGranato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7741/1589) também é boa, mas achei a do @utluiz mais correta.

As duas outras respostas falam principalmente sobre o framework e a performance, que são óbvios para quem não é novato no assunto. **Não estou dizendo que foram más respostas**, só não foram respostas boas para *essa* pergunta. (Fora o fato que o framework é bem estável e performance não é um assunto crítico.)

Comment: Talvez o principal seja rodar em ambientes não-MS-Windows.

Comment: @user2478690 Já ouviu falar do [Projeto Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)?

Comment: Não é a resposta direta à sua pergunta mas é um adendo interessante: "C# é mais lento que C++ por que ele roda em uma máquina virtual e não na máquina nativa".

Comment: pergunta aberta (não específica), muito suscetível a opniões, sujeita a tipos diversos de resposta. Voto pra fechar...

Comment: @pepper_chico Negativo. Se olhar minha nota e atualização, vai ver que, se tem algo que não estou aceitando aqui, são opiniões. Antes de votar para fechar, veja como é a aceitação dessas perguntas no SOpt.

Comment: Como eu já disse, você está fazendo um tipo de pergunta que não está bem definida/descrita, portanto as respostas que aparecem são dispares, baseadas no que cada um entende da pergunta que está confusa, e não estou falando de vontade de dar uma opnião qualquer, o fato é que, não há como fugir disso, pois o próprio entendimento da questão está a escolha do leitor, e o próprio entendimento de respondido está da sua parte, e não uma coisa que se diga imparcial.

Comment: @alacerda O C# não é executado por uma máquina virtual. O código é compilado em código nativo no momento da execução por um compilador JIT.

Comment: C++ pode te dar um salário de mais de quatro casas decimais.

Comment: @Renan A piada foi boa, mas ainda acredito que o que faz o salário depende mais do programador do que da linguagem xD (e, infelizmente, depende mais do mercado do que do programador -- apesar de eu amar C++, quase não existe mais mercado pra ele)

Comment: @bigown Eu não tinha me atentado muito a sua resposta. Mas ela está perfeita.

Comment: Eu resolvi responder porque achei que nenhuma resposta passava nem perto do que você queria. Perfeito é exagero seu, mas tentei achar tudo o que é importante de diferente :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Resumo:

- Sistemas operacionais viáveis, *drivers* para sistemas operacionais existentes ou qualquer operação que precise acesso direto ao *hardware*.
- Gerenciamento e otimização manual de memória inclusive permitindo aplicações *real time*.
- Metaprogramação com *templates* e pré-processamento.
- Herança múltipla.
- Manipulação livre de ponteiros.
- Uma série de pequenas funcionalidades sintáticas e semânticas.

Alguns já disseram que em tese pode-se fazer tudo. Claro que isto é verdade e é claro que há diferenças de como fazer e do resultado obtido. Algumas coisas são mais fáceis de fazer em uma linguagem do que eu outra. De uma certa forma, o pedido de não falar sobre o que é mais fácil elimina qualquer coisa que dê para falar da linguagem em si. Como eu acho que tem maneiras objetivas de falar das facilidades vou tentar responder.

#### Ambiente

- Permite o uso em virtualmente qualquer plataforma enquanto que o C# essencialmente só funcionam em todas as plataformas *mainstream*, que são as que mais importam, os 3 principais desktops, os 3 principais mobiles e diversos servidores.
- Roda sem a dependência de um *runtime* grande. As aplicações podem ficar bem enxutas. C# melhorou um pouco isso.
- Não precisa [*JITtar*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) o código antes de executar. Agora existe o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101).
- Acesso direto ao *hardware* e sistema operacional permitindo a criação de *drivers*, por exemplo.
- Integração mais fácil com C.

#### Gerenciamento de memória

- Tem controle absoluto sobre o gerenciamento de memória.
- Permite controle total do *layout* e local de armazenagem das estruturas de dados. Dá para economizar até o último *byte* e colocar no local ótimo para a situação.
- Liberação determinística de recursos como parte do objeto, impedindo que a liberação seja esquecida porque não colocou um `using`.
- Permite a implementação de algum *garbage collector*.

#### Otimizações

- Permite buscar otimizações que economizam o último ciclo do processador. E tem algumas otimizações mais agressivas no compilador.
- Economia de memória em diversos aspectos.
- Aplicações "totalmente" *real time*. Alguns games com *main loop* muito pesado sem folga para coleta de lixo só são viáveis em C++.
- Se vale de comportamentos indefinidos para obter otimizações e capacidades de acordo com a plataforma.
- Usa os dados numéricos básicos com o *layout* mais adequado para a plataforma.
- Inclusão de código Assembly.
- Ter implementações genéricas totalmente em tempo de compilação.
- Economiza o *overhead* da *vtable* quando ela não é necessária.
- Existem mais escolhas para otimizar códigos mantendo a semântica adequada (*move semantics*, inicializadores e `constexpr` por exemplo).

#### Sintaxe

- Criar pseudo-sintaxe e utilizar outras "facilidades" do pré-processador.
- Agrupar as declarações de membros por visibilidade sem diretiva `#region`.

#### Tipagem

- Possui `union` apesar do C# ter uma forma limitada.
- Tem a segurança que referências (não confundir com ponteiros) não contêm valor nulo. C# terá algo assim.
- Liberdade para criar hierarquia de objetos como quiser, sem uma hierarquia básica pré-definida.
- Utilizar tipos além de `bool` como resultado para desvio condicional.
- Tem vários tipos *string* por padrão.
- Tem mais controle sobre constância de valores, incluindo coerção da constância.
- As funções podem ter o tipo de retorno inferido.

#### Recursos específicos

- Tem funções independentes que não precisam ser membros de classes.
- Herança múltipla de classes abstratas, não só através de interfaces.
- Utilizar uma sub-linguagem com *templates* que é absurdamente mais poderosa que *generics*. Só este item pode se desdobrar em diversos outros.
- Permite `goto` de forma um pouco mais livre.
- Permite criar literais para os tipos.
- Há mais operadores que podem ser sobrecarregados.
- Há mais controle na forma de captura de variáveis em *closures*.
- O `throw` permite lançar qualquer classe.
- Os ponteiros são bem mais flexíveis e poderosos, permite acessos arbitrários à memória.

#### Miscelânea

- Escolha de uma gama mais ampla de modelos de memória para tratar paralelismo e concorrência.
- Pode explodir seu computador e colocar seu cérebro em parafuso (é só piada, ok?)

Algumas dificuldades do C#, principalmente as primeiras listadas podem ser solucionadas em breve com o [.NET Native](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-native-preview/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Por isto é bom ter em mente que o a dificuldade muitas vezes está na implementação da linguagem e não na linguagem em si. Algumas destas limitações são minimizadas há tempos com o [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/).

Alguém poderia dizer que C++ permite criar um sistema operacional ou pelo menos que seria mais fácil. C# também permite e é até mais fácil. Claro que ele pode ter algumas limitações, mas é possível e de fato já foi feito. Pode até precisar de auxílio de outra linguagem (Assembly), mas C++ também precisa.

Alguns itens poderiam gerar vários detalhamentos. Tem tantas coisas que a lista pode crescer indefinidamente.

Ter todas estas capacidades não significa que o C++ é melhor. É diferente. Até porque algumas destas coisas que o C++ pode fazer facilmente é interpretado como **desvantagem**. E o C# também tem muitas coisas mais "prontas" ou mais poderosas que o C++. Apenas a pergunta não tem interessa nisto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 24):

O C++ permite:

- **herança múltipla** contra **interfaces** em C#.
- **gerenciamento manual da memória** contra GC em C#.
- **templates** contra **generics** em C#.
- **inline assembly**.
- Possibilidade de desalocar explicitamente um objeto com `delete`.

Comment: Na verdade, acho que isso não responde à pergunta. Alguém acha que devo excluir?

Comment: Herança múltipla é sempre polêmico, rs. Acho válido como parte da resposta, mas pouco abrangente. Mesmo assim, +1

Comment: Não exclua. C++ pode, C# não. Não é isso?

Comment: @AndréLeria Relendo a pergunta eu achei que você queria algo em termos de resultado final e não recursos de linguagem. Mas se está bom para você, ótimo!

Comment: Resultado final depende mais do programador do que da linguagem. Por exemplo, se fosse C++ vs Java, valeriam Lambda Expressions (e, semelhantemente, Herança Múltipla).

Comment: Gerenciamento manual de memória é possível em C# também. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Comment: @Renan Embora Você pode deletar um objeto, isso não é o mesmo que desalocar a memória, apenas ocorre que o objeto fica eligível para coleta. Tanto que no link que você postou, o tópico *"Explicit Release of Resources"* diz que para liberar recursos abertos imediatamente é recomendado usar um método `Dispose`.

Comment: @utluiz Foi mal. Anotado e aprendido.

Comment: Quando eu disse `deletar`, na verdade estava falando do "destrutor" ser ativado, por exemplo, removendo as referências de variáveis para o objeto. Quem possui o `delete` é o C++ e não o C#.

Comment: Lembrando que código C++ "moderno" evita ao máximo usar new e delete; usa-se objetos em pilha e "smart pointers", e o pattern RAII abençoado pelo Stroustrup :)

Answer (score 13):

Como linguagem, C# não fica devendo em nada, nem em performance.

O problema do C# é que implica num framework que é controlado pela Microsoft, embora haja a implementação livre, o Mono/Xamarin, do Miguel de Icaza. Cheguei a usá-lo em aplicativo "sério" que tinha de rodar em Mac/Linux/Windows e o desenvolvedor alocado preferiu usar C#.

Se você desenvolve código cuja "durabilidade" deva ser muito longa, tem de pensar duas vezes em que poste vai amarrar o burro. Amanhã o framework muda, depois de amanhã ele pode ser abandonado... Veja o que aconteceu com as software houses que apostaram suas fichas no Delphi. Troca a versão do Delphi, quebra tudo, tem muita gente por aí presa a versões paleolíticas do Delphi porque o programa e/ou componentes de terceiros são incompatíveis com as versões novas.

Agora, se você vai fazer algo que não tem de manter por décadas, e é voltado mais à plataformas Microsoft, vá em frente e use C#. Se estiver fazendo apps para Windows Phone, onde por definição você depende umbilicalmente do framework, não há o que discutir.

Comment: +1 por citar o Mono, inclusive o Xamarim (baseado em Mono) é uma solução boa para o problema de desenvolver multi-plataforma para mobile.

Answer (score 12):

C++ é turing-completo, C# também, então com esforço computacionalmente pode ser feito o mesmo com ambas. As limitações aparecerão devido ao ambiente sob o qual elas serão submetidas e não a uma limitação da linguagem.

Comment: +1 por mencionar a completice (essa palavra existe) de Turing.

Comment: @Renan ["completude"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completude)

Answer (score 8):

1. Acesso direto a endereço de memória. Mesmo sendo extendido com C++ a VM não lhe permite acessar diretamente os endereços de memória.
2. Escrever drivers de hardware

Comment: O acesso aos endereços não é permitido com o `unsafe`?

Comment: @AndréLeria sim, é permitido com o unsafe. Acredito que com isso também seria possível escrever drivers de hardware.

Comment: @Flavio Citation needed na afirmação número 2.

Comment: @Renan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886/c-sharp-driver-development

Answer (score 4):

**Nada.**

Ambas as linguagens são turing-completas, como o pepper_chico falou. Isso significa que pode ser muito *mais fácil* fazer algumas coisas em uma ao invés de na outra, mas nada que uma faça é *impossível* de fazer na outra.

Em último caso, é possível escrever um compilador C++ em C# e embuti-lo no programa C#.

Answer (score 2):

Depende da tarefa. Se for crítica em performance o C/C++ é o recomendado. Por exemplo, desenvolvi uma aplicação que roda como serviço, coletando contadores de performance de processos. Ele faz exatamente o que foi projetado, mas tem um custo altíssimo de consumo de recursos se comparado com a versão que foi refeita em C++. São dois fatores de alto custo: memória com picos de consumo grandes e custo computacional com picos de 25 % de consumo.
Em um ambiente onde os recursos computacionais devem ser direcionados ao objeto fim, custos para monitoração não devem superar 3% a 5% do todo. 
A versão em C++ está na fase de homologação, mas já mostrou excelente desempenho com baixo consumo de memória.

Comment: A pergunta se refere a recursos da linguagem, e não performance / uso de memória.

Comment: @AndréLeria então descreva melhor sua pergunta e não deixe-a tão aberta e suscetível a ser fechada. Do jeito que tá, voto pra que feche, por que não é explicita em nada e diz que não busca opnião mas é o único tipo de resposta que se encaixa à forma como ela está.