# O que é .NET Native?

Tags: c#, .net, arquitetura-de-software

Esses dias vi nosso colega [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) comentando sobre a existência do **.NET Native** em [uma resposta sobre C# e C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7740/o-que-o-c-pode-fazer-que-o-c-n%C3%A3o-pode/18811#18811).

Vi que a Microsoft [anunciou](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-native-preview/) em Abril de 2014 o preview do .NET Native. E pesquisando sobre o assunto encontrei essa página explicando http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx .

Pelo o que entendi a ideia é permitir que código escritos em C# sejam compilados para código nativo da máquina. Isso deixaria os aplicativos mais rápidos e usando menos memória.

Como o assunto é novo e estou cheio de perguntas, eis algumas delas:

1. Por que a Microsoft está fazendo isso?
2. Não será mais necessário ter o .NET Framework instalado nas máquinas?
3. Vamos ter que compilar nossos códigos para tipos diferentes de arquiteturas (x86 x64)?
4. Programas que usam o .NET Native vão poder rodar em qualquer tipo de dispositivo e sistema operacional?
5. Vou poder desenvolver um driver ou um sistema operacional com isso
6. Isso é só para apps da Windows Store?
7. Terá alguma diferença em como desenvolvemos hoje?

Quem puder compartilhar um pouco sobre o assunto é muito bem vindo. Inclusive se quiserem editar algo na pergunta afim de enriquecer a questão.

Comment: Algumas perguntas estão respondidas no [FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/vstudio/dn642499.aspx)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pergunta por pergunta.

> Por que a Microsoft está fazendo isso?

**1.** Toda linguagem que usa JIT tem problemas de lentidão em inicialização, e peca em várias otimizações de baixo nível, como uso de instruções vetoriais (SSE[n], AVX) pois estas são custosas para serem realizadas no momento que o JITer é executado.

> Não será mais necessário ter o .NET Framework instalado nas máquinas?

**2.** Não vai ser necessário ter o .Net instalado nas máquinas. A aplicação fará uso apenas da biblioteca `MRT.dll` (Minimal CLR Runtime) e todas as demais bibliotecas do .Net serão estaticamente linkadas na aplicação.

> Vamos ter que compilar nossos códigos para tipos diferentes de arquiteturas (x86 x64)?

**3.** Sim e não. Código nativo é código nativo: x86-64 não executa em x86-32. Mas, por enquanto pelo menos, a Microsoft fará o serviço, já que ela esta disponibilizando o .Net Native apenas para a Store por enquanto. Ela irá realizar a compilação para nativo propriamente dita pois isto a auxilia a garantir mais segurança nos aplicativos disponíveis, além de mais otimizações, já que ela pretende disponibilizar várias versões do aplicativo, uma para cada dispositivo que ele foi otimizado pelo .Net Native para ser executado.

> Programas que usam o .NET Native vão poder rodar em qualquer tipo de dispositivo e sistema operacional?

**4.** Apenas a plataforma Windows será suportada. Por enquanto, ela será voltada inclusive para os Smartphones (aplicativos otimizados executam mais rápidos, melhor UX, menor consumo de energia). Talvez a Xamarin eventualmente desenvolva algo semelhante para o Mono, mas acredito que será apenas para uso em smartphones e não será tão automágico como a versão da Microsoft.

> Vou poder desenvolver um driver ou um sistema operacional com isso

**5.** Não.

> Isso é só para apps da Windows Store?

**6.** Por enquanto sim.

> Terá alguma diferença em como desenvolvemos hoje?

**7.** Sim. Irão haver problemas de incompatibilidades, bugs, partes do .Net que ainda não suportadas pelo .Net Native, etc. [Esta página](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600634.aspx) responde melhor esta pergunta.

Comment: O Mono já tem esta solução faz tempo.

Comment: Que eu saiba não tem não. Você não esta confundindo com compilação AoT?

Comment: Estou falando do AoT. Não é exatamente o mesmo mecanismo mas produz essencialmente o mesmo resultado. BTW, excelente resposta.

Comment: AoT é diferente do .Net Native. Possui muito mais limitações quanto a otimizações, distribuição, geração dos binários, etc. Tanto é diferente, que partes do assembly continua no formato MSIL ao invés de código nativo, devido às limitações da técnica. Além disso, o AoT na grande maioria das vezes esta diretamente associado ao GAC, que também não é o caso do .Net Native. O equivalente AoT do .Net FW é o `ngen`. Não sei se você acompanha o desenvolvimento do Mono, mas o Miguel de Icaza possui alguns artigos excelentes sobre isso. Posso procurar e te passar, caso os encontre, é claro! Obrigado!

Comment: Sem dúvida que o da MS é bem mais evoluído assim como o AOT estava um passo à frente do NGEN. Manda aí. Não acompanho de perto.

Comment: Não encontrei os artigos, mas segue o link para o blog: http://tirania.org/blog//index.html Talvez eu tenha lido sobre o AoT do Mono na lista de desenvolvedores, não lembro... neste caso, não  tenho mais os e-mails (não costumo guardar).