# Por que a Linguagem D é pouco usada?

Tags: advogado-de-linguagem, d

Eu pesquisei bastante sobre a linguagem, já usei os compiladores, IDEs (Eclipse, Mono, CodeBlocks).

Achei ela "boa de mais pra ser verdade". Tem toda a estrutura da sintaxe de Java/C# (Que ao meu ver é mais produtiva), mas é compilada como se fosse C++ .Tem muitas bibliotecas importantes , por ser compatível com as de C/C++.

Mas ela é muito esquecida ou pouco usada (aqui nem sequer tinha a *tag* `D`). O que é que ela tem de tão ruim? Falta alguma implementação importante, ou algum uso muito irregular da memória, problemas de herança múltipla, construtores ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Agora tem :D​​​

Comment: A sim, obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago, cara essa pergunta é muito subjetiva. Vão te encher de votas negativos. Essa pergunta requer opinião e não uma resposta de fato direta, como é o site(SOpt). Bem, não estou te criticando, por favor, apenas te dando uma dica quanto à pergunta.

Comment: Resposta sarcástica: é que pra usar linguagens como D, o cara tem que aprender pelo menos um pouco a programar. Jà viu o tanto que tem de PHP, jQuery, e coisa com RegEx no site? :P

Comment: Bem, o que eu estava tentando saber é se ela possui algum 'problema' , erros de compilação, incompatibilidade, falta de algum recurso importante etc.

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago brincadeiras à parte, você pode acrescentar esse comentário na pergunta, acho que ela fica até mais específica. Por exemplo, acrescentar que você quer saber se ela é uma linguagem madura, se está pronta para uso, e essas coisas que vc falou. Valoriza a pergunta se você [edit] e acrescentar essas dúvidas mais técnicas e menos dependentes de opinião. Além disso, comentários são muito efêmeros, e nem todo mundo lê. Sobre a tag, o simples fato de você usar faz com que ela exista no site. O que falta é só preencherem o wiki da tag com a descrição.

Comment: Olha vou ser sincero, não acho que seja possível responder, pois é uma questão de opinião, mas a minha humilde opinião é que as IDEs ajudam muito algo se tornar popular. Delphi e VisualStudio ajudaram (na minha opinião :) ) a tornar o ObjectPascal o C++, C# ... Tanto que muitos programam em certas linguanges, mas nem sabem realmente no que programam. Pelo que olhei o D tem um editor de GUIs voltado pra ele e mas é bem limitado se comparado a outros, fora que não vem acompanhado do instalador: http://www.dprogramming.com/entice.php

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , MonoDeveloper é uma ótima IDE .

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago Foi basicamente o que eu disse, se entendi o seu comentário, o MonoDevelop sim e provavelmente é um exemplo que talvez ajuda a justificar o porque uma linguagem se torna popular (no caso dele c# e F#).

Comment: Uma impressão que tive um tempo atrás era que a linguagem estava em beta perpétuo. Depois congelaram a versão 1 e passaram a desenvolver a versão 2, mas em vez de passar a ideia de estabilidade para a versão 1, tudo indicava que ela era deprecated (e atualmente já é mesmo). Também achei a documentação (e evolução) das bibliotecas bastante confusa, eles pareciam focar mais no núcleo da linguagem do que no ecossistema.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Marketing

Um dos motivos é que o marketing é mais importante que a capacidade técnica.

Mas isso é uma simplificação. É óbvio que ter uma aceitação grande é importante e isso foi ficando cada dia mais difícil. Para as pessoas acreditarem em algo precisa ter certeza que haverá bastante suporte para todo ecossistema da linguagem. Isto pode ser fornecido por grandes empresas, por isso o marketing é importante.

Em alguns casos uma linguagem ganha tração por ser a única ou a melhor opção para programar algo que as pessoas estão interessadas, o que aconteceu com as linguagens da Apple. Já viu como Objective C e Swift são cheias de falhas? O sucesso se deve ao iOS adotá-las e este sim ser um sucesso. Como este perdeu um pouco de tração as linguagens foram junto.

O mesmo vale pra Java, C#, ou ainda PHP, Python, JS (só ela podia ser usada em *browsers*), etc. Claro que linguagens de comunidade possuem marketing também, só não é pago, é mais orgânico. E sucesso atrai sucesso.

Um dos erros estratégicos deles talvez tenha sido tentar pegar o programador do C++. A linguagem não é uma substituta para o que o C++ resolve bem. Mas vendem como se fosse. De fato, andam mudando a estratégia, tarde demais.

## Ecossistema

O fato é que D não só não tem esse apoio de uma grande empresa ou o apoio de muitos pequenos usuários (o que se chamaria de grande comunidade), mas também não tem um ecossistema confiável e claramente evolutivo.

Falta muita coisa em torno da linguagem. Pouca gente capacitada (em vários sentidos) e comprometida tem ajudado fechar os buracos ainda existentes. Falta rodar bem em todas as plataformas, por exemplo. Não estou só falando de IDE de alta classe, falo de bibliotecas (até mesmo da qualidade das básicas existentes) e ferramentas em geral.

Não quer dizer que não esteja melhorando, nem que não tenha umas coisas bem legais, mas muita coisa deixa a desejar quando se compara com C++, C# e Java que são os concorrentes mais diretos de D.

O fato de existir vários compiladores, cada um com seus defeitos, e até durante um bom tempo ter uma competição entre bibliotecas padrão não ajuda também. Ela é muito pequena para ter fragmentação. Adota o LLVM como oficial e fortalece o que é bom.

O fato da biblioteca padrão escolher um estilo mais funcional e de meta programação em detrimento do paradigma queridinho dos programadores (OOP, cof, cof) também não ajuda (isto não é defeito, mas cria uma impedância com a popularidade).

## Não é revolucionária

D é ótima. Mas não é essa maravilha toda também. Ela tem diversos problemas, como qualquer outra. As pessoas que se aprofundam percebem que vão trocar de problema, que ela não é uma solução definitiva. Você irá ganhar aqui e perder ali. Um agravo é que as pessoas que potencialmente iriam usar D são mais espertas e conseguem ver que não é o *holly graal*, não é o que acontece com PHP, Python ou JS que as pessoas só compram o marketing sem questionar.

Para citar um exemplo, o [*garbage collector* da linguagem não é dos melhores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13574552/221800) e prejudica muito o seu funcionamento. Só sua existência tende a afastar quem precisa do C++. Quem programa em C++ normalmente quer um controle melhor da memória e outros aspectos. [D não é capaz de fazer tudo sem custos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/97207/389), nesse ponto D está mais próximo do C#. E dizer que pode programar em D sem usar o GC é marketing, na prática isso não acontece, sem tornar a linguagem uma das mais improdutivas, muito mais que C++. Mas isso pode mudar, mas haverá problemas.

Gerar um executável puro não é essa vantagem toda. Java e C# são compiladas e executam código de máquina, só precisam de um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) antes. Mais ainda, nada impede que o [código de máquina seja gerado direto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). De fato, o C# já pode fazer isso e está cada vez mais fazendo melhor com a evolução do [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) e o ["novo" .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Apesar de ter acertado em muitas coisas, quando você começa olhar a linguagem mais profundamente começa perceber que ela cometeu vários erros. Ela não é perfeita, toda linguagem é assim. Conhecendo mais começa ver a linguagem mais igual às outras, começa ter menos motivos para trocar o que já está fazendo sucesso por algo incerto. Tem que ter um motivo forte para trocar uma coisa por outra. E D não resolve um problema de forma muito melhor.

Tem muita coisa que parece revolucionária, mas usando percebe-se que não é tudo isso. E C++ não é tão ruim assim, o competidor direto é bom o suficiente. E C++ teve tempo para ir melhorando alguns dos seus defeitos enquanto D ainda não tinha um público formado, todo mundo vê melhoras no que era ruim, há um *roadmap* claro em curso e está tudo acontecendo, em D pouco acontece.

Falta uma [*killer application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_application) para D. Falta um nicho onde ela caia como uma luva.

## Problemas em geral

Nenhum desses problemas sozinhos seriam suficientes para justificar o pouco uso da linguagem, elas apenas ajudam a justificar.

- Existem várias *strings*.

  Apesar disso dar flexibilidade é confuso ter que lidar com os vários tipos. Talvez uma mudança sutil salvasse a linguagem desse problema. Escolher uma como *default* claro e deixar as outras como opções, já padronizaria um pouco. E fica pior, porque há confusão na implementação e não é intuitivo usá-las. Você espera pegar um caractere e pega um *byte*. Algumas pessoas acham que é um erro que elas sejam mutáveis.
- *Arrays* fora da tipagem padrão

  Eles foram implementados de forma que foge do padrão do sistema de tipos da linguagem e possuem algumas características que, no mínimo, podem ser consideradas esquisitas.
- Custo extra

  Ela possui abstrações com custo extra, que vai contra o preceito de C/C++, linguagens que D tenta competir. O GC é apenas o mais óbvio deles.
- Já carrega legado

  Algumas novas características foram colocadas posteriormente de forma feia e parece gambiarra e não algo da linguagem. Mesmo as que ficaram boas vieram tarde, *timing* é importante. Algumas são feias desde o início e faltou um pouco de bom gosto ao Walter, que é um excelente criador de compiladores.
- Não resolveu tudo

  Alguns erros do C++ continuam presentes. Cada dia alguém acha um defeito novo. Basicamente todo mundo já sabe os defeitos de C++. A percepção faz diferença aqui mais do que a realidade.

Enfim, houve um pouco de teimosia no início e lançamento definitivo um pouco prematuro que inviabilizou mudanças mais radicais quando as críticas começaram aparecer.

Alguns dos defeitos podem ser subjetivos, mas é o que conta.

## Profissionais qualificados

Um exemplo contrário é o PHP. É uma linguagem muito pior, mesmo com a "evolução" de hoje, nem tem, ou não tinha, um ecossistema tão bom assim. Mas ela resolvia um problema importante na época, ela se beneficiou muito de ser focada em um nicho. Ela era uma linguagem muito prática para trabalhar com web. Ela já tinha uma biblioteca boa embutida e uma estrutura que executava fácil com um servidor HTTP. Por ser dinâmica e sem cerimônia atraiu muita gente para fazer sites simples e rápidos. Como ela começou ter sucesso atraiu mais sucesso. Profissionais começaram aprender para quebrar um galho. Aí empresas começaram abrir vagas porque tinham profissionais. E mais gente aprendeu porque tinham vagas. Entendeu a diferença?

Em função disso tudo faltam profissionais qualificados. Aí entramos no problema do ovo e da galinha. Nenhuma empresa vai adotar uma tecnologia que ela não consegue achar profissionais. As pessoas não procuram aprender porque não tem vagas disponíveis. Alguma coisa precisa acontecer pra quebrar este círculo vicioso.

## Conclusão

Nos fóruns oficiais e outros relacionados existem diversas discussões sobre o assunto, sempre com participações dos principais membros da linguagem, o Walter Bright e o Andrei Alexandrescu.

É uma pena, a linguagem realmente é bem interessante e eu provavelmente estaria usando-a se tivesse mais sucesso.

Mas dá para usar tranquilo. Ela não é uma porcaria, muito pelo contrário. [O Facebook está usando bem](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/l37h5s$2gd8$1@digitalmars.com). Ou estava :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas o que? O facebook usa D ?

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago e não é de hoje:  http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/facebook-adopts-d-language/240162694

Comment: Só uma nota, acredito que o facebook deixou de usar o `D`, pois os repositórios que o usam foram movidos para https://github.com/facebookarchive, o único que encontrei foi o https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift que na verdade é um conjunto de códigos mas não é um uso exclusivo @Bacco

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é bom lembrarmos que nem tudo deles é open source, mas se eu achar alguma informação relevante, compartilho aqui.

Comment: Ecossistema é a palavra chave, mudanças tem custos e tem de ser pesado se terá retorno, melhor é relativo, o quanto de um legado importante terei de reescrever para estar no mesmo ponto que estou hoje ?