# A linguagem C# é recomendada para ser distribuída online com banco de dados?

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, c++, segurança

É muito fácil pegar o código inteiro de um programa C# usando o .NET Reflector.

Seria possível eu colocar a *mesma segurança* em um programa C# que um programa feito em C++? Achei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893/best-method-to-obfuscate-or-secure-net-assemblies) no Stack Overflow em inglês mas até no comentário diz que é possível ainda obter o código do programa.

Não acho legal qualquer um ver meu código, não estou dizendo que C++ é totalmente seguro ou algo do tipo, confesso que não sei muito sobre o assunto. Mas por tudo que pesquisei, [C++ não seria possível obter todo o código como é possível em C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715430/is-there-any-concept-in-c-like-reflector-in-net).

Mas a pergunta é sobre C# e não C++. Gosto muito de C# e queria saber se realmente posso confiar em usar uma senha de banco de dados em c# apenas usando um dos programas para "esconder o código" do .NET Reflector. Se não, C++ seria uma boa opção?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O problema da segurança está no programador e não na linguagem. Quando usa-se a técnica errada obterá a solução errada.

## Segurança do executável

Em qualquer linguagem dá para pegar senhas inseridas dentro do seu executável. A solução é simples: não faça isto!

C++ produz executáveis nativos, portanto código de máquina, mas isso não quer dizer que senhas estão protegidas, pelo contrário. Nem mesmo o código está protegido. Um *disassambler* consegue refazer o código em *Assembly*. Existem descompiladores que também conseguem produzir código C/C++ vindo de um executável. Os resultados não são bons, mas é possível.

A descompilação do C# permite gerar códigos melhores, mas ainda assim não são perfeitos. E tem como gerar código nativo com C#, já existia antes com [Ngen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e agora tem mais facilidades com o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) (obsoleto).

Não se preocupe muito com o fato do código poder ser mais facilmente descompilado, e em uma circunstância específica (isso nem sequer está relacionado à linguagem em si e sim a forma como ela está implementada, o que é uma característica transiente). Isso causa menos problemas do que parece, na verdade nunca vi causar um problema de fato.

## Proteger senhas

Primeiro tente não colocar senha no executável ou mandar em um arquivo. Tem certeza que é necessário? Não tem outra forma de fazer isto? Seja criativo!

Se precisa de uma senha, por que não deixar isso na mão do usuário? Não é uma solução melhor deixar o usuário criar uma senha para ele (ou você criar de alguma forma) e o acesso ser feito com ele digitando a senha?

Tem [técnicas para não precisar colocar a senha na solução](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se realmente não tiver outro jeito e tiver que colocar a senha do banco de dados junto com a aplicação não tem porque colocar dentro do executável. Coloque em um arquivo auxiliar. Tem até um padrão do .NET para fazer isto. E faça de forma criptografada, obviamente. Isso protege a senha, não 100%, mas protege.

Já pesquisou no SO, [pesquise pelo motivo certo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12657792/221800). Veja que o [.NET já pensou nisso e tem solução pronta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2160568/221800).

Para esse problema não faz a menor diferença usar C++ ou C#. Na verdade, é provável que ache menos soluções prontas adequadas em C++ do que em C#.

Você pode fazer perguntas específicas sobre o assunto ou outras coisas, mas cuidado porque sua ideia de segurança está muito longe da realidade. Não acredite em nada sem ter uma informação que confirme isto inequivocamente. Para isto estamos aqui.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).