# Arquivo .exe no Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Como faço para gerar um executável que rode em qualquer máquina sem o .Net instalado?

Aquele que fica na pasta `bin/debug` não serve por que ele precisa do .Net pra executar.

Comment: A plataforma .net (C#, VB .net, ASP .net) necessita obrigatoriamente do framework para executar, você pode fazer, no visual studio usando c ou c++, mas na minha opinião, não compensa, você pode criar um arquivo de instalação que instale o framework junto à sua aplicação você pode ver como criar um instalado [aqui](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2014/11/27/criando-instaladores-para-aplicativos-net/)

Comment: Qualquer máquina windows(Vista+) tem o .net instalado. Ou você se refere a outro SO?

Comment: Me refiro a Windows mesmo, até consegui gerar o executável que roda em qualquer máquina com a opção  "Publish..." mas ele é na verdade um instalador, e também não é isso que quero

Comment: Quer um único arquivo .exe, com todas as .dll embebidas?

Comment: As respostas dadas já dão uma boa noção do problema, mas eu sugiro na próxima você especificar a linguagem em uso. O Visual Studio é uma IDE, e não uma linguagem de programação. Como na maioria das IDEs, você pode programar em várias linguagens diferentes, e nem todas são baseadas em .NET - O pessoal só está conseguindo responder, pq pela sua descrição, testou com alguma linguagem baseada em .NET, senão nem isso daria pra ter certeza.

Comment: @user8465 A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 7):

O normal é precisar do .NET instalado mesmo. É possível fazer um executável e incluir todas as dependências dispensando o .NET padrão instalado na máquina se puder usar o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) (que agora se torna o padrão). Ainda precisará mandar junto a estrutura do .NET, mas pelo menos não exigirá que ele faça parte do Windows como parte do mecanismo do sistema operacional (não precisa instalar nada, basta copiar tudo que é necessário).

Também dá para obter efeito semelhante com [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), mas é menos recomendável na maioria dos casos.

Logo teremos [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) para uso geral que criará executáveis totalmente sem dependências, se quiser. (Na verdade ele deve não receberá mais investimentos).

Fora isso a única solução é incluir o .NET Framework no instalador e incluir no sistema operacional, se ele não tiver.

A não ser que exista a opção de fazer em outra linguagem que não exija o .NET, como C ou C++.

Isso ficou um pouco datado, fazia sentido na época da pergunta. Ainda é verdade, mas estamos falando de tecnologias que agora estão em modo de suporte apenas.

Agora tem o [NativeAOT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/568799/101). E depois passou ter o AOT direto no .NET normal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Complementando: agora é possível gerar binários independentes com o [Native AOT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/568799/o-que-%c3%a9-o-native-aot).