# Como criar um executável monolítico da aplicação .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-assembly

Não gostaria de fazer o *deploy* da aplicação cheio de DLL, queria algo simples, sem instalador, queria gerar um só arquivo executável, mas o .NET é todo baseado em DLL.

Tem como gerar um executável único?

Comment: De uma olhada no [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630). [Esta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551311/merging-dll-with-exe) no SO pode te ajudar a "configurar"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executável monolítico mesmo só com o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101). Ou Mono ou agora com o .NET 5 usando o *runtime* do Mono. No .NET 7/8 ficou bem mais fácil usando o chamado [AOT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/568799/101).

Com o .NET Core é fácil gerar um executável único, mas ainda precisará do *runtime* separado, pelo menos reduz para uma única DLL. E não precisa ter o .NET Framework instalado.

Mais recentemente [no .NET Core pode embalar tudo em um único arquivo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), ainda que não seja um único executável. Para maioria dos cenários isso já resolve o que quer.

Se for uma aplicação normal .NET Framework pode usar o [`ilmerge`](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge) que é feito pra juntar tudo em um arquivo só.

Mas se tiver DLL não gerenciada, em C ou C++, por exemplo, aí ele não funciona. O único jeito é adicionar a DLL como recurso e fazer a separação antes da execução, pelo menos você garante que o transporte para o *deploy* vai ok e se o usuário acabar apagando acidentalmente você pode restaurar do executável principal. O máximo que dá para fazer é embalar tudo em um arquivo, mas serão vários arquivos internos dentro desse.

Algumas pessoas preferem fazer manualmente até mesmo DLLs gerenciadas.

Outras preferem outros utilitários mais completos. Talvez o exemplo mais popular seja o [Fody Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura), que alias faz parte de um utilitário maior bem interessante. Outros:

- [ilrepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack)
- [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/) (vem com mono)
- [.NETZ](https://github.com/madebits/msnet-netz-compressor)
- [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/#merging-dlls) (pago)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).