# MSIL pode ser convertido para native code?

Tags: .net

Posso converter um CIL de .NET Framework gerado de um executável em C# para um código *native code*?

Se sim, a partir deste *native code*, posso transcodar para outras linguagens como C++?

Se não, existe um nível mais baixo do CIL para que possa compilar para outras plataformas o mesmo Assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.NET Framework é uma das implementações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101) do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101), da [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) que de fato, até por força de especificação gera um CIL conforme a pergunta denota.

A pergunta acaba sendo, mesmo involuntariamente, capciosa. É possível, porém, de forma geral, [não faz sentido pegar um CIL gerado para rodar com o .NET Framework em código nativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240858/101). Não que não dê, mas para dar um resultado útil daria um trabalho monumental e ainda teria que ser em partes específicas.

Mas [é possível ter um CIL convertido para código nativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192912/101).

Primeiro vamos deixar claro que o CIL não é executado, ele é convertido para código nativo antes de executar. Mas entendo que não seja isto que está falando. Acho que quer que gere um executável com código nativo.

É possível sim com [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101). O [Mono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135744/101) já fazia isso, e o [Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90871/101) faz onde precisa. Estas são outras implementações parecidas, mas não idênticas ao .NET Framework.

Com o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) fica mais próximo porque ele tem menos dependências, mas ainda não é bem o nativo. tanto que existe o [CLR "antigo"](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx), o [do Core](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) e o [do nativo](https://github.com/dotnet/corert).

Não faz muito sentido pegar um código nativo e tentar gerar código C++ nele. Mas é possível [gerar o código C++ direto do CIL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html).

[Agora só faz sentido usar o .NET 5 (Core)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

[Melhorou no .NET 7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/568799/101).

Informações úteis:

- [Qual .NET devo utilizar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183229/101)
- [O que é e como funciona o .NET Platform Standard?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113264/101)
- [Por que o .NET Core foi criado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225927/101)
- [Compatibilidade entre .NET Core 2.0 e .NET Framework 4.7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230655/101)