# Programas escritos em C# dependem do .NET Framework para rodar?

Tags: c#, .net, instalador

Uma vez que compilado um código C# depende do .NET Framework instalado na máquina para rodar, similarmente ao Java?

Comment: @vnbrs Mas o que eu quero entender é: há como fazer o programa de forma que não dependa de .NET Framework? Eu quero começar a estudar C#, mas houverem dependências para rodar os programas, eu não vou. Quero algo mais "plug and play".

Comment: @vnbrs Mas dessa forma podem haver problemas de incompatibilidade, não acha? Já instalei programas que pediram uma versão específica do .NET para rodar.

Comment: @inovapixel sinceridade, não ... resumindo de um modo geral.

Comment: Link bem útil para reflexão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609993/difference-between-net-framework-4-6-net-native-and-net-core

Comment: Sinceramente, código compilado para arquitetura e SO específicos não tem nada de "plug and play", escrever código portável é uma coisa que exige extrema disciplina e não é trivial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hoje não mais, ainda que dependa de um *runtime*, como essencialmente toda linguagem depende, claro que o C# exige um *runtime* um pouco mais pesado porque precisa gerenciar a memória, *threads* segurança e outras coisas, além de possuir uma biblioteca muito forte.

Quase desde sempre pode usar o [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) que não é o .NET Framework e não precisa estar instalado na máquina. Tem lá suas desvantagens, mas funciona bem.

Agora tem o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) que também não precisa ser instalado de antemão, com ele essencialmente fica livre de dependências, então já resolve o que deseja. Claro que ele tem limitações, não roda tudo o que o .NET Framework roda, aí tem que ver do que precisa.

Também tem o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) que é como se fosse um programa feito em C ou C++. Ele ainda não roda tudo, mas está evoluindo. Mas em 2020 ele está relegado e o futuro é todo o .NET 5 que é o Core. Começando no [.NET 7 tem o AOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que faz quase o mesmo de uma forma mais interessante.

Rodar bem depende do programador fazer certo. Dá um pouco de trabalho, mas feito certo vai bem. Fazer certo e de acordo com as necessidades é uma tarefa para o desenvolvedor resolver. Pode dar um pouco mais de trabalho, mas é factível.

Importante dizer que a maioria parte das aplicações em C ou C++ precisam de um *runtime* que já está no sistema operacional, alguns com dificuldades de versões, não tem milagre, sem nenhuma dependência não existe, pelo menos em sistemas operacionais "normais".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Não conheço nada que não necessite de uma dependência que seja pra rodar. Só se essa dependência for compilada junto com a aplicação.

Se você pretende entregar sua aplicação para ambientes Windows, o sistema já vem com o framework instalado. Sua maior preocupação seria qual versão do .NET usaria no seu aplicativo. Pode ver [aqui](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/) qual versão de .NET Framework sai com cada versão do Windows.

Se for uma aplicação instalável, você pode adicionar o .NET Framework na versão desejada ao seu instalador.

Tudo isso que eu disse é anulado se você quiser uma solução web com o ASP.NET (e variantes). No client-side o .NET não é necessário, somente no servidor. A única dependência seria o navegador, mas espero que não chegue a incomodar.

Answer (score 1):

"Programas escritos em C# dependem do .NET Framework para rodar?" A pergunta está meio aberta, mas, de uma forma geral e usando a arquitetura padrão, ***Sim***. Para executar os aplicativos feitos em c#, você ***precisa*** do runtime do .net.

Quando você cria um aplicativo em C++ e usa o gcc para compilar, você geralmente gera código nativo, ou seja, um binário específico para a plataforma (processador e SO) que você está usando.

Quando você programa em c# e compila, você gera uma linguagem intermediária chamada de IL (similar ao byte code em analogia) e esta por usa vez é que é compilada e executada em tempo de execução pelo ambiente do .net.

Este mesmo ambiente realiza o gerenciamento de memória por você, esse é um dos principais motivos para usar uma plataforma como essa, existem vários problemas de segurança ligados ao simples gerenciamento de memória, sem falar nos bugs. Algo parecido com os Smart Pointers do c++, so que estes estão mais ligados ao escopo imediato, em ambientes gerenciados com o do .net, uma heuristica é usada para controlar o momento real em que os blocos de memória são desalocados, você pode pedir, mas, a especificação não garante que o garbage collector realizará a coleta quando você pediu, ele que escolhe o momento mais adequado para limpar a memória que você não está mais usando. Logico que isso se aplica ao que chamamos de código gerenciado, você também pode invocar código nativo (Win32) dentro de uma aplicação .net, ai a coisa segue o fluxo normal das coisas. Você pode chamar uma dll feita em c++ dentro de um código em c#.

O formato de executável do Windows é o formato PE, nele estão os cabeçalhos que permitem ao sistema operacional executar e gerenciar o espaço de memória dos aplicativos, pelo que lembro, alguns campos foram inseridos nos cabeçalhos do formato PE que permitem ao SO saber se o arquivo é um executável para o .net e por baixo dos panos, chamar o framework ou solicitar sua instalação.

Essas facilidades, bem como o fato de que os frameworks geralmente vem com o Windows, acabam gerando confusão sobre a necessidade ou não do runtime, mas, ele existe e está lá para você.

O compilador do runtime (JIT) é inteligente e por questões de performance, ele mantem um cache dos códigos e instruções que já foram compilados para melhorar a performance.

O fato do código dos executáveis ser uma linguagem intermediária, também nos leva ao fato de que pode ser lido e 'descompilado' com mais facilidade, esse é um dos motivos da existência de ofuscadores que dificultam a leitura e descompilação de código intermediário.

Um ponto interessante a se discutir é que geralmente, existem complicações maiores do que as que você está tendo na escolha de uma linguagem, para uma aplicação funcionar, como já foi dito, não há como não ter uma dependência de API, SO ou código de terceiros (código legado é bem comum).

Meu tempo trabalhando com .net me ensinou mais a ter cuidado com binários de terceiros e dependências, em alguns casos raros, a versão do Framework. Mas, dada a sua pergunta, minha sugestão é verificar a plataforma para qual você pretende desenvolver, o .net vai bem além do c# ou do clr e é uma plataforma integrada em vários níveis de solução, mas, é logicamente muito mais madura em seu potencial quando se visa a plataforma de produtos Microsoft.

Referências:

**[Código Gerenciado - Microsoft (inglês)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-code)**

**[Componentes da arquitetura .net (inglês)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/components)**

Comment: Alguem me explica o -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Existem alternativas que nao necessitam da framework .net.

O [turbo.net studio](https://turbo.net/studio) elimina a depedencia da framework .Net. Nao faco a minima ideia como é que funciona, pois nunca usei.
Da [página de features deles](https://turbo.net/studio/features) está escrito o seguinte

> Eliminate .NET and Java Dependencies
>
> Execute .NET, Java and AIR-based applications with no separate
>   installation steps or runtime versioning conflicts. The Turbo virtual
>   machine supports all versions of the .NET Framework and Java,
>   including .NET 4.0, 4.2, and 4.5.

Traducao livre:

> Elimina depedencias do .NET e Java
>
> Executa aplicacoes .NET, Java e AIR-based sem necessitar de instalacoes
>   adicionais e sem conflictos de versoes de runtime. A máquina virtual turbo
>   suporta todas as versos do .NET Framework e Java,
>   incluindo .NET 4.0, 4.2, e 4.5.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306997)

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/133327)

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Feito.

Answer (score -3):

Mas é claro que depende https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/getting-started/introduction-to-the-csharp-language-and-the-net-framework, logo no início C# se chamava J++, a microsoft queria uma linguagem que se assemelhava ao java, mas devido a briga judiciais com a SUN ele mudaram para C# e depende totalmente do .NET assim como Java depende da JVM

Comment: C# nunca se chamou J++., e me parece que isto não responde ao que foi perguntado.