# Exibir janela sem frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, framework

Como eu posso exibir uma janela, sem usar *frameworks*?

Por exemplo, exibir a janela do console ou outra sem o .NET e outros *frameworks*.

Comment: Creio que seja com https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms632679, mas acho que vai ser muito mais trabalhoso que usar o `Form`

Comment: Você pode trocar "exibir janela sem frameworks" por "executar programa sem computador", por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem *frameworks* usando C# até agora ainda é impossível, mesmo no [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101). De forma geral nem mesmo sem o .NET ou outra implementação do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) não dá (que já é um *framework*). Se nada disso resolve então desista do C# até ele ter uma versão sem um *framework* (o que duvido que seja possível, tá, talvez seja só com [um monte de biblioteca no lugar de *frameworks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101), mas ainda tenho dúvidas, e não vai rolar).

Todo acesso às funções de console já é feita com o .NET e não sei se podemos chamar esta parte de *framework*, então estritamente falando, sem um *framework* específico já está fazendo nesta parte, ainda que precise de um *framework* para o todo. Se não quer usar estas funções é possível acessar a [API do Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (ou outro sistema operacional) diretamente, mas vejo zero vantagens nisso.

Se o que deseja não é console tem [toda a API do Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Só vejo vantagem em usar o que ainda não está disponível no .NET.

Não sei se eu não chamaria a API do Windows de *framework* também, ela tem uma filosofia muito próxima de um de *framework*.