# Compilar uma aplicação .NET em um executável self-contained

Tags: c#, .net, compilação, deploy

Eu queria saber se é possível compilar uma aplicação .NET Framework em apenas um arquivo executável. Sem que hajam arquivos `.dll` externos.

Efetuei algumas pesquisas mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Nesse caso, acredito que o ideal é montar um instalador.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos É o que fazemos atualmente. Queria compilar uma nova aplicação em apenas um arquivo para facilitar sua entrega junto à aplicação antiga. As duas trabalharão juntas.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2014/11/27/criando-instaladores-para-aplicativos-net/

Comment: @Barbetta Atualmente nós utilizamos o Inno Compiler citado no artigo.

Comment: Na mão: http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2011/06/embed-dlls-easily-in-a-net-assembly/

Comment: Opa, vou testar isso.

Comment: @GabrielFerreira Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Se você só quer juntar tudo basta usar o [ILMerge.exe](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge). É uma ferramenta padrão do .NET Framework.

Se puder aceitar uma DLL pode usar o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101), mas não pode rodar qualquer aplicação.

Se quer um executável mesmo (não gerenciado), pode usar o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101), mas ainda não está disponível para todo tipo de aplicação. O [Mono já dá](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/mkbundle/).

Desde o .NET Core 3.0 é possível [publicar tudo como um único arquivo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Vou testar esse ILMerge.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar o [`Costura`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/) para juntar todos as dependências do aplicativo num só `.exe`.

Basta adicionar ao seu projecto, que ao instalar o pacote, é adicionado um [ficheiro `.xml` com a configuração da fusão](https://github.com/Fody/Costura#configuration-options-link) e é adicionado um novo [`import`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92x05xfs.aspx) ao `.csproj` que traz os [`targets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t50z2hka.aspx) que o `Costura` necessita para fundir a aplicação durante a fase de compilação.