# É possível incluir o necessário do .NET para rodar um aplicativo independente?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-core, .exe

O título pode ser confuso, mas o objetivo é fazer um aplicativo escrito com .NET ser executado sem o .NET Framework. Na prática isso é quase impossível porque o aplicativo depende das bibliotecas do .NET para executar, mas na minha teoria, mesclar o .NET Framework junto o executável irá fazer ele independente do .NET, tendo todas suas bibliotecas dentro do próprio executável.

A mesclagem não seria inserir todos as bibliotecas do .NET Framework no executável, e sim somente as que o executável depende.

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível se usar o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101). Também é possível como Mono, mas esse [está cada vez menos necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

O .NET Core tem algumas limitações ainda. Até 2019 deixará de ter a maioria delas e poderá portar sua aplicação completa para ele. Mas hoje boa parte já consegue ser portada. Algumas coisas nunca poderão ser portadas, mas de qualquer forma são coisas que não deveria usar de qualquer jeito, são recursos considerados problemáticos e obsoletos.

O .NET Core é autocontido e não depende de nada instalado previamente. Você monta o executável só com o que precisa. Ele ainda precisa de pelo menos uma DLL além do executável. Para ter executável 100% nativo e sem DLL precisaria do [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101), mas que por enquanto só serve pra um tipo específico de aplicação.

Se depender do .NET Framework *full* não tem o que fazer. E na verdade se já tem o .NET adequado na máquina nem precisa porque tudo já está lá.

De qualquer forma .NET Framework passará ser legado. Será suportando, evoluirá, mas bem lentamente, e só o que for fácil e necessário. O Core é o futuro para quase tudo, especialmente projetos novos.

Comment: Então, o .NET Core cria um executável do .NET com suas bibliotecas próximas ao executável ou dentro do executável? Outra coisa, se o .NET está incluído na saída, o executável do .NET Core pode ser convertido para um executável do Windows (sem .NET)?

Comment: Melhorei a resposta.

Comment: @CypherPotato o mundo .NET é bem diferente do mundo nativo. O executável do .NET somente poderá ser convertido para um executável Windows (sem .NET) através do .NET Native, que é bem restrito e específico mas, ao usar o .NET Core e fazer um deploy como autosuficiente, seu app vai com tudo o que é necessário para executar (sem depender de instalar .NET no computador). Mas não, não é nativo.