# PHP ou Java ? Pontos positivos e negativos

Tags: php, java

Estou usando o **PHP** há pouco tempo, e mesmo usando um **framework,** usufruindo da **Orientação a Objetos** eu ainda **não** tenho a **percepção** de ver as **limitações da linguagem.** Por exemplo, se uma linguagem suporta mais conexões que a outra, ou se uma é mais fácil de criar um sistema seguro.

### Situação

Vamos dizer que sou dono de um conjunto de faculdades(FI). Tenho 4 faculdades nos 4 cantos de SP. Deixei meu bd centralizado em um único ponto e desejo criar hotsites e páginas de acesso exclusivos para o corpo docente marcar eventos, provas, trabalhos e etc. Para os alunos, todo um controle de notas, trabalhos, e ficar sabendo dos eventos que ocorrerão nas 4 faculdades.

Comment: Este tipo de pergunta não é aceito pela comunidade. Leia [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/488/7261)

Comment: Não há forma de comparar as duas linguagens sem que especifique um problema em concreto. Sendo assim além de estar fora do escopo como disse o @Andrey é baseada em opiniões e ampla demais a sua pergunta.

Comment: @Andrey Peço desculpas e agradeço pelo "toque". Sinalizei pro moderador excluir.

Comment: Sem problemas. =) Agora que ela tem uma resposta, eu não sei se e possível excluí-la. Sua pergunta provavelmente ficará apenas fechada.

Comment: Confesso que votei a favor da pergunta _Gorilla vs. Shark_, e o título dessa pergunta aqui me remeteu àquela pergunta quase que instantaneamente. Mas ao ler o conteúdo dessa aqui fico me perguntando se não é possível a aceitarmos. O que tem de tão bizarro nela que devemos fechá-la? Qual a grande diferença dela para essa: [O que o C++ pode fazer que o C# não pode?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7740/3117), por exemplo?

Comment: @Math abre discussão no meta sobre a pergunta.

Comment: @Math este tipo de pergunta precisa ser muito bem feita para não atrair opiniões. Precisa ter um foco muito bem claro, dar uma parâmetro definido do que está buscando. Vantagens e desvantagens em geral, sem nenhum contexto é exatamente o motivo de cair no Gorilla X Shark. É possível fazer a pergunta de um jeito que ela pode ser útil, o AP precisa se esforçar para deixar claro o que ele **precisa**. E porque é tão importante ser muito claro nisto? Justamente para não dar margem para respostas inúteis, para evitar as opiniões ao invés de fatos. Não é o tipo de pergunta, é o jeito dela.

Comment: A pergunta que referiste [O que o C++ pode fazer que o C# não pode?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7740/o-que-o-c-pode-fazer-que-o-c-n%C3%A3o-pode), é uma pergunta bem especifica e não é uma comparação de qual a melhor. Esta pergunta pelo titulo e conteúdo quer saber qual linguagem escolher, qual a melhor ou pior. O que acontece, como podes ver na resposta abaixo é "depende", acaba por ser demasiado ampla e baseada em opiniões e por isso mesmo e vendo [Gorilla vs Shark](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark) é também fora do escopo.

Comment: "rede social de grande porte" e um "ERP" são termos amplos de mais, se você não sabe pesar o que é melhor entre Java e PHP, tenho certeza de que não está planejando construir nenhum dos dois a curto prazo, sugiro que comece com algo realmente próximo a sua realidade. O quê, de verdade você está querendo fazer?

Comment: @bigown Sendo assim sim :) Ou seja, se o AP conseguir perguntar algo que não atraia opiniões ele pode sim saber a diferença entre as duas linguagens, de forma específica.

Comment: @Math Estou fazendo essa discussão. Mas é mais pra saber pontos importantes que o PHP não é tão eficaz como o Java. Em que tipo de situação eu devo pensar em migrar de linguagem.

Comment: @allan de acordo com o dicionário, eficácia significa: "Alcançar os resultados planejados. alcançar os objetivos, alcançar a meta." Ou seja, as duas podem ser eficazes, dependendo de qual é sua meta. Quanto a "quando migrar de linguagem", acho que pode ser considerado amplo de mais, pelo menos eu não sei se conseguiria responder de forma satisfatória. Eu acho que sua pergunta é salvável, mas ainda não sei te dizer como perguntar de forma que fique objetiva e consequentemente aceitável pela comunidade, provavelmente pq ainda não entendi direito onde você quer chegar.

Comment: Allan, acho que ainda faltam mesmo mais informações para que sua pergunta possa ser reaberta. Como disso o Math, os exemplos que você deu são muito vagos e genéricos (você mesmo disse "vamos dizer que..."). Bom, você disse que já usa PHP. E em Java, você sabe programar? Se você não sabe e tem um problema *imeditado* para resolver, não precisa nem pensar: use PHP. Aí estude Java com calma, e vai começar a perceber a diferença entre as linguagens, e as limitações de cada uma.

Comment: Agora estaria bom ?

Answer (score 10):

Dito isso, para a sua pergunta se PHP é sempre mais rápido do que Java, a resposta é depende. Qualquer comparação entre duas linguagens distintas provavelmente terá essa resposta.

Veja que seu teste simples deixa de lado muitas coisas que podem interferir diretamente no resultado. O fato de você ter comparado uma aplicação web (php rodando sobre Apache) com um programa "standalone" (Java rodando diretamente sobre a jre) e com um programa em C (compilado, e portanto "naturalmente" mais rápido). Você teria que, no mínimo, estar comparando JSP rodando sobre Tomcat (que é a face web do Java) com PHP para ter um teste que começa de forma "aproximadamente equivalente".

E isso é só o começo, mas não vou me estender nos problemas com seu método de teste. Lembre-se que todas essa linguagens aplicam otimizações que podem fazer muita diferença em determinados cenários.

Vou me concentrar na sua pergunta de qual a linguagem mais adequada, e a resposta novamente é: depende. Vou supor que estamos falando de aplicativos web (php, jsp, apache, tomcat).

A questão que fica é: por que você precisa de um sistema que responda tão rápido? Por que a velocidade é, para você, o fator mais importante, em detrimento da segurança, confiabilidade, robustez, facilidade de manutenção? Uma grande parcela das aplicações web e sites (99% por cento eu diria, mas não tenho referência respeito) não precisam responder de forma rápida como respondem as aplicações desktop, ainda mais se considerarmos a variação na qualidade e velocidade da redes (Banda Larga, 3G, Fibra).

Se você possui conhecimentos equivalentes de Java e de PHP, então simplesmente sugiro que use as duas. Nada impede você de trabalhar com duas linguagens diferentes, ainda mais se for freelancer. No momento que fizer a análise do projeto, já poderá decidir, baseado no escopo, o que vai usar. O bom é que você estará sempre "treinando" cada uma delas, o que pode ser útil quando algum projeto ou vaga requerer alguma delas em específico.

O maior porém, até onde sei, é um consumo maior de processamento e memória no caso do Java (em especial, se for web), o que torna hospedagens com Java mais caras, mas de resto eu diria que ambas são equivalentes em recursos e capacidade (considerando, é claro, as diferenças de sintaxe, estrutura e implantação).

Enfim, escolha a que mais se sentir bem (ou as duas) e seja feliz. E, quando quiser, mude.